# Display long labels in x-axis using Chartist

Tags: javascript, node.js, chartist.js

I am using [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) and [svgdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgdom) in Node.js to generate a line chart. But the label names are too long and they run over each other.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

I saw [#375 issue](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/375) in Chartist and they tried to tilt the labels using CSS, but i think rotating the X-Y axes is a better idea, if possible.

What can i do here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about flipping it, but as another option, you could make the graph a larger fixed width. Then make it's parent container smaller(screenwidth) and make the entire chart scroll-able horizontally.

Comment: that is a good way too, but i would prefer no horizontal scrolling. my webpage https://ifct2017.github.io/data/query?text=show%20food%20with%20high%20calcium now uses reduced number of lables. thanks.